# How to use setup datasource for HSQL for junit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hsqldb

I have written a repository class that takes a `javax.sql.DataSource` as a constructor arg, and has some basic CRUD operations on it. I now want to write junit tests for it. I want to use HSQL as my DB for these tests, but I'm not sure how to set up the DB the way I want. With a Spring app, I've put something like this in my app-context for the test:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:mySQLForDB.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

However, what I'm wanting to test isn't in a Spring app. Is there anyway in code to setup the datasource and setup up the DB from a sql file? Basically something that would be functionally equivalent to what Spring is doing with the `<jdbc:embedded-database>` tag.

Comment: Well, if it is a junit test for your repository class, I reckon that Spring is still a valid solution. It is simple to create a test application context with just your repository bean and the `<jdbc:embedded.database>` that can be put in the `src/test/resource` folder and if you just add the Spring dependencies to the test classpath, the application will remain unaware of Spring.

Comment: I've gone down that thought process. Worst-case scenario, I'll just use Spring for the tests, but if possible, I'd rather not be dependent on Spring to run the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider trying h2?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:mytestdb",
            "sa", "");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    st.execute("create table foo (id integer)");
    st.execute("insert into foo (id) values (1)");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from foo");
    while (rs.next()) {
        int result = rs.getInt("id");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    conn.close();
}
```

HSQL has the same way but haven't tried it.
Look at [this link](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch01.html#N101CA)

I hope this helps.